# How can i do that in access form

Tags: vba, subform

i want make thing like this by cod (non wizard)

[image: im]

when i'm pressing button 1 sub form show table1 and when i'm pressing button 2 sub form show table2 
how can i do that ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok thanks i found it
code of button 1

```
Me!Child4.SourceObject = "Table.Table1"
```

code of button 2

```
Me!Child4.SourceObject = "Table.Table2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Behind Button 1 - OnClick VBA Event:

`Forms!MainFormName!SubformName.Form.Recordsource = "Table1"`

Behind Button 2 - OnClick VBA Event:

`Forms!MainFormName!SubformName.Form.Recordsource = "Table2"`

Comment: it is open table
i want open table in sub form

Comment: See updated answer. You cannot do this operation with a macro.